# Set ToastrModule Properties from database at run time angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I am working with ToastrModule in angular 8. I have set its configuration when imports module like below.
But my question is how to pass these configuration from database when application load . Because I have no idea how to pass configuration at run time to modules in angular Module

```js
ToastrModule.forRoot(  
  {  
     positionClass:'top-left',  
     closeButton: true,  
   }  
)
```

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: You want to get these values from database `positionClass:'top-left', closeButton: true,  ` and then want to set these here dynamically when application loads ?

Comment: yes , but these are two properties just for example,there can be numbers of properties. I just mentioned here Toastr.forRoute(), there can also be configuration files for other modules. The basic question is how to pass configuration file to forRoute when application loaded